# Breakpoints in files in chrome not being hit when using webpack sourcemaps

Tags: google-chrome, webpack, breakpoints

I have a breakpoint in a source .js file (loaded via source maps) that when I point to in with chrome dev tools in source tab, it is not hit. Sometimes I can get them to be hit if I click the format button {} but its hit and miss.

Any ideas?

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.1.20",
    "babel-loader": "^6.1.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.3.13",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "material-ui": "^0.14.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "stylus-loader": "^1.5.1",
    "tape": "^4.2.2",
    "webpack": "^1.12.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.12.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.1.19",
    "moment": "^2.11.2",
    "normalize.css": "^3.0.3"
  }
```

webapck:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    './app/app.js'
  ],
  output: {
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'dist/main.js'
  },
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      },
      { test: /\.styl$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' }

    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".js", ".css",".styl"]
  }
};
```

Comment: Could be related to https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2145 TLDR: try 'inline-source-map'

Answer (score 2):

So this seems to be an [issue with webpack and chrome in the past that was brought up](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2145).

The interim solution was to set it set the `devtool` option to `source-map` or `inline-source-map` but note, this will cause your compile time to increase.

As of Webpack 3 the issue has improved, but the problem is in the interplay between Chrome and Webpack with their changing code bases.

With Webpack 3 I've had success with the following configuration:

`devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map'`

Answer (score -1):

Comment devtool

```
//devtool: 'source-map',
```

Add to plugins

```
new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
        filename: '[file].map',
        include: ['app.js'],
        exclude: ['vendor.js'],
        columns: false
    })
```

Comment: Can you give any details on what this does or why it works?

Comment: if I have correctly understood what the problem was that chrome was not possible to put a breakpoint in some cases, columns (defaults to true) When false column mappings in SorceMaps are ignored and a faster SourceMap implementation is used.

Comment: columns can be [set to false](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/5b5775f9e2fc73fea46629f2d6a3ed7a1f8424d3/lib/WebpackOptionsApply.js#L221) by using `devtool: 'cheap-source-map'`

Comment: For me, this seems to give the same result as `devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map'`

Comment: How do you know that? There is nothing about commenting out `devtool` and using plugin instead in official docs.